# Error de sintaxis en Mi BD

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema con MySQL sin ingreso un id por URL me da el siguiente error:

http://mvc-bienes-raices.test/admin/propiedades/actualizar.php?id=01

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your
> SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
> version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 in
> C:\laragon\www\MVC-Bienes-Raices\Class\propiedad.php:229 Stack trace:
> #0 C:\laragon\www\MVC-Bienes-Raices\Class\propiedad.php(229): mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM p...') #1
> C:\laragon\www\MVC-Bienes-Raices\Class\propiedad.php(221):
> App\Propiedad::consultarSQL('SELECT * FROM p...') #2
> C:\laragon\www\MVC-Bienes-Raices\admin\propiedades\actualizar.php(18):
> App\Propiedad::find(false) #3 {main} thrown in
> C:\laragon\www\MVC-Bienes-Raices\Class\propiedad.php on line 229

Pero si lo agrego de esta forma no me da el error

http://mvc-bienes-raices.test/admin/propiedades/actualizar.php?id=1

Aquí les dejo mi `INSERT`

```
   //? Read||Listar
    // Llistamos todas las propiedades
    public static function all()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM propiedades";

        $resultadoPropiedad = self::consultarSQL($query);

        return $resultadoPropiedad;
    }

    //Buscar propiedades por su id
    public static function find($id){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM propiedades WHERE id = ${id}";

        $resultado = self::consultarSQL($query);

        return array_shift($resultado); //Array_shift nos retorna el primer elemento de un arreglo
    }

    public static function consultarSQL($query)
    {
        // Consultar la base de datos
        $resultadoPropiedad = self::$db->query($query);

        //Iterar
        $array =  []; // Arreglo reutilizable
        while ($registroDB = $resultadoPropiedad->fetch_assoc()) {
            $array[] = self::crearObjeto($registroDB);
        }

        // Liberar memoria
        $resultadoPropiedad->free(); // podemos ignorar esto, pero ayudamos el servidor liberando memoria

        // Retornar
        return $array;
    }

    // convertimos de arreglos a obejtos ya que active records solo acepta objetos
    protected static function crearObjeto($registroDB)
    {
        $objeto = new self; // new self = la clase padre (Propiedad)

        foreach ($registroDB as $key => $value) {
            if (property_exists($objeto, $key)) { //property_exists nos confirma que la propiedad exista. compara el objeto con su key.
                $objeto->$key = $value; // le asingamos los valores
            }
        }
        return $objeto;
    }
```

No sé como arreglarlo.

Comment: Ahi estas mostrando un insert, y el error habla de un select.. no parecen ser lo mismo...

Comment: Tienes razón. Ya lo edité.

Comment: y el campo id de que tipo es?

Comment: id || INT(1) || Primary Key || NOT NULL || Default//Expresión lo dejé vacío.

Comment: Ya ves que el campo es un INT y cuando le pasas 01 como valor da ese error pues no es un entero.  Lo que tendrias que hacer es, antes de usarlo en el select, calcular si $id es entero, y si no lo es parar la ejecución y devolver un error. Aparte de eso tu consulta es susceptible de inyección SQL pues no usas sentencias prepare.

Comment: Listo, entendido. Apenas estoy aprendiendo la verdad, pero voy a investigar sobre esas sentencias preparadas. Gracias.

Comment: Ahora mismo lo poco que se contra inyeccion SQL es ingresar datos sanitizados.